# CSS styling changes take 2-3 seconds to show when adding a class to a DOM element in an Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, android-webview

So lets say I have a DOM element, bunch of text in a div

```
<div id="bio"> I'm Captain America! </div>
```

Now I put a onClick listener on this div and in the onClick listener callback function, I do

```
$('.bio').addClass('red')
```

and in my CSS file, I have this line

```
.red { color: red; }
```

If I try it from a normal web browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc)... the text instantly becomes red color on clicking. However, if I do it from a Android Webview embedded in an Android app.. then the text takes 2-3 seconds to become red.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue - I had a blocking HTTP request call in my WebAppInterface (Javascript Interface listener) which was causing the UI to freeze to 2-3 seconds while the call completed. Replaced it with a non-blocking (async) call and now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

While it usually doesn't take 2-3 seconds, some mobile browsers have a default delay of 300ms on click events.

You can fix this by using FastClick, a javascript library that removes this delay

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: It seems to be a little faster, but still there is a time lag between the styling changes being applied.